# error-page in web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception

I am preparing for SCWCD Exam.I have a query in this question.

Which two from the web application deployment descriptor are valid? (Choose two.)

```
    A. <error-page>
        <exception-type>*</exception-type>
        <location>/error.html</location>
       </error-page>
    B. <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Error</exception-type>
         <location>/error.html</location>
      </error-page>
    C. <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
        <location>/error.html</location></error-page>
    D. <error-page>
            <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
            <location>/error.html</location>
        </error-page>
    E. <error-page>
            <exception-type>NullPointerException</exception-type>
             <location>/error.html</location>
        </error-page>
```

The correct answer is CD.but why cant java.lang.Error be valid since Error is a subclass of Throwable.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc of `Error` and `Exception` classes:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions [...]
>
> The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch [...]

It has nothing to do with their types, it is more like a design choice.